# Is there a compiler switch in gcc that prevents leaking of random data in final executable?

Tags: gcc

EDIT: I made wrong assumptions here, gcc works fine, read the answer below.

I find pieces of source code, directory structure and other random data from development computer in compiled object files that end up in an executable file after linking.

Of course, this is just random data from compiler's process memory, probably reused buffers that holded source code or other files, not cleaned properly before reuse.

In many cases this is not a problem but sometimes this leakage reveal too much. What I find most problematic about that is it's unpredictability: today it reveals source of some unimportant library, but tomorrow it could reveal some private key or something similar.

Is there some regular way to prevent this, some switch that will force gcc to clean up its buffers between uses or some other solution ?

EDIT:

Ok, here's an example, by compiling qrcodegen.c from:

https://github.com/nayuki/QR-Code-generator/tree/master/c

with this command line:

gcc -c -Wall qrcodegen.c -O9 -o qrcodegen.o

result is here, look at offset 0x668C:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WZRlCsjr4CALfi5pmsbd3fLeVsnnxGsa

if linked into executable that content appears
in .rdata section exactly as you can see it in object file.

Comment: What makes you think it is a leak? `gcc` does sometimes emit debug symbols, but I doubt it would emit garbage data from memory into the compiled file.

Comment: Yeah, there's something seriously wrong with GCC if it's putting random strings from memory into your binary. Could you edit your question to include a small example program and a list of the strings that turn up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're observing is based on the use of `assert`.  Since `assert` will print a message on failure that usually (always?) includes the actual assertion test (`21 <= qrsize && qrsize <= 177 && 0 <= x && x < qrsize && 0 <= y && y < qrsize`), the filename, and the line number.

If you compile with `-DNDEBUG`, you'll disable the `assert`s.  I haven't dug through the resulting object file, but the snippet you pointed out earlier isn't there.